# Probability of at least one job candidate-company pair with matching interests

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, statistics, discrete-mathematics

Suppose that there are $M \geq 1$ job candidates and $N \geq 1$ companies with job openings. Each candidate (independently, uniformly at random) develops a serious interest in one of the $N$ companies and each company (independently, uniformly at random) develops a serious interest in one of the $M$ candidates. What is the probability that there is at least one company-candidate pair that are seriously interested in each other?

---

I could write a simulation. But is there a closed form solution that depends on $M$ and $N$? How would one go about this problem? Can the probability be written as a sum?

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a closed form expression, but you can certainly write it as a sum.
$$
1-\frac{1}{M^NN^M}\sum_{\sigma\colon[M]\to[N]}\prod_{j=1}^N(M-\#\sigma^{-1}(j)).
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Is it possible for you to elaborate what you mean by sigma: [M]->[N] and #sigma^-1 ?
For example, how can it be implemented in a spreadsheet? 
Is it a mathematical way of expressing the inclusion-exclusion principle?

Comment: I'm summing over all functions $\sigma$ from $\{1,2,\dots,M\}$ to $\{1,2,\dots,N\}$ (i.e., the preference of candidates).  $\#$ is just the number of elements, $\sigma^{-1}$ is the inverse image set function, so the product is taken over each company to prefer candidates other than those that would match.

Comment: Ok, so for $M = 3$ and $N = 3$ we use the fact of equal likelihood and say that for $A \subset S$, the desired probability is $1 - |A|/|S|$ where $A$ is the 'no match' outcomes. 

$|S| = 3^3 3^3 = 729$ and $|A| = 18 \times 6 + 6 \times 8 = 156$

and the desired probability is $1 - 156 / 729$

Can you verify that?